# difference between byChunk() and chunks() in D

Tags: d

In D, I can iterate over a file "a chunk at a time" in the following ways:

```
foreach (ubyte[] block; chunks(myfile, 4096))
```

or

```
foreach (ubyte[] block; myfile.byChunk(4096))
```

I cannot seem to find any major differences in the [documentation](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_stdio.html).
Is there any semantic difference, or is it only syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

going through the [source](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/blob/master/std/stdio.d) you can see that

`myfile.byChunk` will have a [`struct`](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/blob/master/std/stdio.d#L1083) with the range properties (front empty popFront)

while [`chunks`](https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/phobos/blob/master/std/stdio.d#L2132) has a struct with the `opApply` (which is not a range)

it looks like the `chunks` struct is more efficient in a straightforward foreach as it bypasses the abstraction of File and it will attempt to allocate the buffer on the stack while `byChunk` will always allocate on the heap and has to deal with the abstraction layer (which are all non-virtual functions so can be inlined but still...) but has the advantage of being an actual range

Comment: I suppose this is a satisfactory answer, although now I should research the trade-offs between ranges and opApply.